# HTML helper tag textbox make it readonly

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

How can I make the following field Readonly..?

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age, new { value = "0"}) %>
```

Comment: @karthik , may be question is dublicate, but Darin's second suggestion is important for this question. Because this is usable for only strongly-typed-helpers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could set the `readonly` attribute:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age, new { @readonly = "readonly" }) %>
```

And if you wanted to disable the textbox (same as readonly for the user, but its value will not be sent to the server when the form is submitted) you could use the `disabled` attribute:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age, new { disabled = "disabled" }) %>
```

As far as setting the default value for the textbox is concerned, I would recommend you doing this at your controller, when populating the model:

```
MyViewModel model = ...
model.Age = 0;
return View(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age, new { @readonly = "readonly" }) %>
```

You can pass multiple attributes at a time while calling a helper like this

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age, new { @readonly = "readonly", @class="Text", style="INLINE STYLE" }) %>
```